# setOnItemSelectedListener on spinner?

Tags: android, json, spinner

i am trying to set onItemSelectedListener on my spinner so if one value get selected from spinner it will show that selected value. my code is,

```
 ArrayList<String> items = getCountries("data.json");

    spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerStandard);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.second_layout,R.id.txtStandard,items);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private ArrayList<String> getCountries(String fileName){

    JSONArray jsonArray = null;
    ArrayList<String> cList = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        InputStream is = getResources().getAssets().open(fileName);
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] data = new byte[size];
        is.read(data);
        is.close();
        String json = new String(data, "UTF-8");
        jsonArray=new JSONArray(json);
        if (jsonArray != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                String standard = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("standard");
                if(!cList.contains(standard))
                    cList.add(standard);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (JSONException je)
    {
        je.printStackTrace();
    }
   return cList;
}
```

I've tried googling for all the options and as many other variations as I can think of and can't find any useful results, so I'm obviously missing something.

what will be the correct way of doing this type of situation ?

Comment: Yes you are on right way. Using `onItemSelectedListener` you can achieve you task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setOnItemSelectedListener is the listener called when an item is selected in spinner:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        // your code here
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
        // your code here
    }

});
```

Now since you know the position of item selected, you can use it to fetch the item from the list of items in your spinner list.

Comment: should i write the following code sample below this statement- spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: yes you can    write it after setting adapter as well

Answer (score 0):

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override   
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,long id) 
    {
        //Called when item is selected, use position of item to find it from list of items
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0)
    {
        //Called when no item is selected
    }
});
```